# Laravel 5.4 - Return single row from joined table

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

I have model Album (table albums) and model Photo (table photos). When I'm fetching all albums to page, I would like to display first photo from each album as album image.

Album model:

```
public function photos()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Photo');
}
```

Photo model:

```
public function album()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Album');
}
```

Query:

```
public function getAlbums()
{
   return DB::table('albums')
        ->join('photos', 'albums.id', '=', 'photos.album_id')
        ->select('photos.title', 'albums.title AS album_title', 'albums.slug AS album_slug')
        ->get();
}
```

It returns all photos with album title. How to modify the query to return only first photo from each album? How to use LIMIT 1 in joined table? Or is there another way to do this? Thanx.

[Reslut](https://i.stack.imgur.com/is6vL.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not do things the Laravel way instead of raw DB queries?  There's a trick to doing exactly this.  First in your Album model, add a method (I use `latest()` but maybe you want to do an `oldest()`, or some other limit [described in the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queries#ordering-grouping-limit-and-offset)
):

```
public function firstPhoto() {
    return $this->hasOne('App\Photo')->latest();
}
```

Now you can do:

```
public function getAlbums() {
    return Albums::with('firstPhoto')->get();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace `get()` with `first()` since get returns an object instance, first will return a single instance;

```
public function getAlbums()
{
   return DB::table('albums')
        ->join('photos', 'albums.id', '=', 'photos.album_id')
        ->select('photos.title', 'albums.title AS album_title', 'albums.slug AS album_slug')
        ->first()

}
```

Comment: It returns only first album with first photo. I need all albums with first photo of each of them.

Comment: add griup by albums or create a function in albums model to fetch first pic on each album